# Prove an inequality containing abolute value and square root

Tags: inequality

[image]

(x,y are both greater or equal to zero)

I'm trying to prove this inequality, but I'm stuck for a long time.

My idea is that because it is in a form that the left part is smaller or equal to a square root thing, I first square the left part get $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|^2=|x+y-2\sqrt{xy}$|. Then I tried to find this is smaller than or equal to something that contains $|x-y|$

Thus, I wrote:$|x-y-2\sqrt{xy}+2y|\leq|x-y|+2\sqrt{xy}+2y$. Then I can't move anymore.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2927048/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2422791/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/569274/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/946804/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7C%5Csqrt%20x%20%20-%20%5Csqrt%20y%7C%20%5Cle%20%5Csqrt%7B%7C%20x%20-%20y%20%7C%7D%24)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: We know $x,y\geq 0$. Hence, $x-y=(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})$.